# What is the "vector analysis" used in The Bletchley Circle?

Tags: the-bletchley-circle

In the second episode of season one of the series *The Bletchley Circle*, the protagonists refer to a technique they call "vector analysis" that was used at Bletchley Park, and then apply it to a crime they are investigating.

What is this technique and what variables were they using with it?

Answer (score -3):

Vectors describe magnitude and direction. Vector analysis is used at crime scenes when detectives study blood spatter patterns and bullet pathways (for example) to determine where someone stood when they were shot, how far away the killer stood, etc. In mathematics, vectors are typically drawn as arrows of varying length.

Here is an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodstain_pattern_analysis#Determining_angles_of_impact) from wikipedia which shows how blood spatters are translated into vectors in order to determine angles of impact.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is totally unrelated to what is being referred to in the scene in question.